# How to stream images to the browser with Django

Tags: python, django, streaming

Forgive me if I am using these terms incorrectly, I'm pretty new to the concept of streaming and I haven't found many resources in Googling that talked about the best use cases for streaming.

What I have right now:

Browser makes a requests for an image to a Django endpoint

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://www.example.com/api/images/51234/
img.onload = function() {
    $('#my-img').attr('src', this.src);
}
```

Django turns around makes another request to a service for an image

```
import requests

def get_image(request, img_id):
    response = requests.get("http://api.myexample.net/album/123/img/{0}".format(img_id))

    return HttpResponse(res.content, mimetype="image/jpeg")
```

My understanding of this process is that Django will read all of the binary information for this image into memory before turning around to deliver the response to the browser.  Is there a way I can stream it directly down to the browser rather than waiting for the image to be delivered completely to Python?

I have read the documentation for the [StreamingHTTPResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse) class but all the examples show simply reading a file off of the server's disk and passing it to a StreamingHTTPResponse, not getting it from another service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you can do that

```
import requests
# have this function in file where you keep your util functions 
def url2yield(url, chunksize=1024):
   s = requests.Session()
   # Note: here i enabled the streaming
   response = s.get(url, stream=True)

   chunk = True
   while chunk :
      chunk = response.raw.read(chunksize)

      if not chunk:
         break

      yield chunk


# Then creation your view using StreamingHttpResponse
def get_image(request, img_id):
   img_url = "http://api.myexample.net/album/123/img/{0}".format(img_id)
   return StreamingHttpResponse(url2yield(img_url), content_type="image/jpeg")
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to get download image content using `requests.get`. Lets say:

```
def viewFunc(request):
    image_url = 'some.image.url.jpg'
```

you can pass the url to your html file simply via context.

```
return render(request, 'some_html.html', {'image_url':image_url})
```

Then in html use like :

```
<img src="{{image_url}}" id="image_id">
```

Or if you are using ajax:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'image_url':image_url}))
```

Then in html:

```
success : function(response){
    var image_url = response.image_url;
    $('#image_id').attr('src',image_url);
}
```

This way django will only pass the url to image view and the image will render from frontend. There is no need to download image using requests.get since all the  browsers are capable of generating image from image tag.

Comment: Sadly I think I do need to do the requests.get - what I did not include is that the service I'm calling is an authenticated endpoint that needs to authenticate a token with the request before it will return the image.

Comment: You can check if the image link being generated is static or not.